# svn up taking a very long time, or stuck; repository corrupted?

Tags: svn

Is this a sign my repository is corrupted?

I ran `svn up` via ssh and quit in the middle (Ctrl+C) once I realised I made a mistake, then I tried again and it said to run `svn cleanup` so I did, ssh'ing into the machine. Then I tried `svn up` and waited and it never showed anything (still hasn't).

I then did `svnadmin verify /root/of/repos` and it successfully verified every revision (over 2400).

Then I suspected the copy was bad. So I checked out a new copy and replaced the old version. Checked out fine. However, that copy has the same symptom of basically running `svn up` in a way indistinguishable from a hang.

Anything else I can do or is my repository (and all changes) gone? :-(

Comment: Made ssh verbose, it gets stuck at: ```debug1: Sending command: svnserve -t```

Comment: Please answer your own question using the `Answer your Question` button, don't put "Solved: … " at the beginning. Thank you!

Comment: In my case. When I try to update some project it would got stuck on some file. I think there are some files are corrupted because of migrating svn from corrupted hd drive to other drive.

Answer (score 2):

Try to checkout the working copy on the server(by using the file:// URL), just to check that the repository is corrupt (I doubt that).

I think something is wrong whith you ssh tunnel

Answer (score 2):

This had to do with my SSH tunnel. But also a technicality I have not seen mentioned in the SVN manual about the tunnel.

I could checkout with something like:

```
svn co svn+ssh://somesitehost.com/var/svn/repos
```

But I could not use `svn up` with that checked out copy. When I checked out, SSH automatically prepended my user name (which is the same as `somesitehost.come`) and used my SSH key for the handshake. This is normal behaviour.

Using `svn up` in this checked out copy left SSH stuck after authentication

```
debug1: Sending command: svnserve -t
```

I'm not sure what it was. The solution (I suppose) is to always use your full URI (with your name) to your tunnel. `somesitehost.com` won't cut it.

`svn+ssh://tatsh@somesitehost.com/var/svn/repos/somerepo/trunk` will always work.

I do find it strange that I can check out without a full URI but I cannot do anything else with the repository after that. Might as well be `svn export`.